# How to serialize Out of the box bean

Tags: java, serialization, oracle-adf, weblogic11g

We are developing web application using ADF. In this application we are using some classes which are available in third party jars.

We are using Weblogic 11g cluster environment for deploying this application.
While running the application we are getting error log like "**object can not be serialized**". We are getting this error wherever we are trying to use the classes available in third party JAR.

Now my concern is how to serialize these classes? or is there any other way/ setting using which we can avoid this error?

Comment: Is it possible that something you're passing is being serialized? Perhaps for session store or some other reason. If this is the case, I would recommend that you check what you are sending. It may have to implement Serializable. It's also possible that you should not be serializing this item. A database connection for example should not be serialized.

Comment: In which way you are using third party classes?